# Twin primes and circles.

Tags: prime-numbers, euclidean-geometry, twin-primes

For $n$ prime, noticed a pattern whenever a twin prime $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ is the *only* point satisfying the circle

$x^2+y^2=n^2 + (n + 2)^2$

then $\Large \frac{x^2+y^2}{2}$ is prime.

**Example (prime)**

Let $n=149$, then

$x^2+y^2=45002$

has only **one** point $(149,151)$ on the circle, so

$\Large \frac{45002}{2}$ is prime.

[image: t_p]

**Example (not prime)**

Let $n=29$, then

$x^2+y^2=1802$

has **two** points $(11,41)$ and $(29,31)$ on the circle, so

$\Large \frac{1802}{2}$ is not prime.

[image: not_p]

**Question**

Is there an underlying method to explain this pattern?

**Edit**

As noted in the comments

> The Sum of squares function formula for the number of ways to write
> the sum of 2 squares indicates this as well, not only for twin primes
> but also for any pair of consecutive odd integers...

To verify, I updated the program to allow any consecutive odd integers and it holds true when $n \bmod 10 = 3,5,9$.

It's related to this sequence https://oeis.org/A089593

> Numbers $k$, such that $k^2 + 2k + 2$ is prime.

Comment: The answer is yes: the theory of [Gaussian integers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer) can be used to prove this, and not only for twin primes but for any pair of consecutive odd integers. Unfortunately I am not sure how familiar you are with this theory. If not, the answer will need to be either very long or incomplete ( "fill the gaps for homework" kind).

Comment: E.g. the only points on the circle $x^2+y^2=394=2\cdot 197$ are $(\pm 13,\pm 15)$ or $(\pm 15,\pm 13)$ as $197$ is prime - never mind that $15$ itself is not!

Comment: More generally, there is a bijection  between the integer solutions of $x^2 + y^2 = k$   and $x^2 + y^2 = 2k$

Comment: At least that bijection is simple to demonstrate: $(x,y)\mapsto (x-y,x+y)$

Comment: Even more general than the other answers: consider the quarter-circle with centre $0$ and radius $n$ or $2n$ (where $n$ is odd). If there is only one point on that quarter-circle with integer coordinates, then $n$ is prime. This is true regardless of whether those integer coordinates are primes or near each other or anything.

Comment: @Greg Martin Suppose radius $n=39$, then $(15,36)$ is the only point on that quarter circle, but $n$ is not prime? I'm testing your nice idea and would like to see this working. Thanks!

Comment: woops, you're correct because we can scale any smaller circle into a bigger circle. I should have said: if there's only one point on that quarter-circle with integer coordinates *and those coordinates' greatest common divisor is 1*, then $n$ is prime.