# Pythagorean triples, primes and circles.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, euclidean-geometry, pythagorean-triples

I was working recently on [Twin primes and circles.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4520612/twin-primes-and-)

Thanks to Greg Martin, a nice generalization was conjectured in the comments section

> Consider the quarter-circle with center $0$ and radius $n$ or $2n$
> (where $n$ is odd). If there's only one point on that quarter-circle
> with integer coordinates and those coordinates greatest common
> divisor is $1$, then $n$ is prime.

Testing the conjecture, I noticed a pattern of Pythagorean triples appeared.

For example, with radius $n=13$, it found only one point $(12,5)$ on the quarter circle (ignore point symmetry $5,12$)

[image: py_inf]

Similarly, it found these triples

```
(radius, x-coord, y-coord)

(5       4        3)
(13      12       5)
(61      60       11)
(181     180      19)
(421     420      29)
(1741    1740     59)
(1861    1860     61)
(2521    2520     71)
(3121    3120     79)
(5101    5100     101)
(8581    8580     131)
...
```

Notice the pattern shows **both** the radii and y-coord's are primes!

**Question**

Is it possible to show there are infinitely many prime y-coord's,
thus proving two Pythagorean prime sides occurs infinitely often?

Comment: Isn't $(5,12)$ also on that quarter circle? You really need a distinct point on the eighth of the circle.

Comment: Good idea about the 1/8 circle portion! Edited to mention about ignoring point symmetry. Thanks.

Comment: The relatively prime pythagorean triples with $y$ are of the form: $$(x,y,z)=(2uv,u^2-v^2,u^2+v^2),$$ where $u,v$ are relatively prime and not both odd. Then you want $u^2+v^2$ and $u^2-v^2$ to both be prime. But $u^2-v^2=(u-v)(u+v),$ so you need $u =v+1$ and then we want $2v+1$ and $2v^2+2v+1$ to both be prime. Letting $p=2v+1,$ this means you want primes $p$ with $\frac{p^2+1}2$ prime.

Comment: Note that in your table, radius is always $\frac{y^2+1}2.$ It seems unlikely to be easily shown that there are infinitely many such $p$ such that $(p^2+1)/2$ is also prime.

Comment: I can't think of any non-linear integer polynomials $P$ for which it is proved there are infinitely many integers $n$ such that $P(n)$ is prime. But if your conjecture is true, then $P(n)=2n^2+2n+1$ takes infinitely many prime values.

Comment: Sorry, dropped a word in my first comment. Should have been "... with $y$ **odd**..."

Comment: @Thomas Andrews I was excited about your idea that both $\space y\space$ and the radius might be prime when 
$\space r=\dfrac{y^2+1}{2}\space$ but, if you look at the triples in $\space Set_1\space$ of my answer or, if you generate many more triples with $\space my\space $ formula (with $\space n=1$), you will see that this is always true when $\space r-x=1.$
\begin{align}
F(1,1)&= (3,4,5)\\
F(1,2)&= (5,12,13)\\
F(1,3)&= (7,24,25)\\
F(1,4)&= (9,40,41)\\
F(1,5)&= (11,60,61)\\
F(1,6)&= (13,84,85)\\
F(1,7)&= (15,112,113)\\
F(1,8)&= (17,144,145)\\
&\vdots
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We begin with a formula that generates the subset of Pythagorean triple where $\space (C-B)=(r-x)\space$ is an odd square, i.e.
\begin{align*}
&A=y=(2n-1)^2+&&2(2n-1)k\\
&B=x=               &&2(2n-1)k+2k^2\\
&C=r=(2n-1)^2+&&2(2n-1)k+2k^2
 \end{align*}

We can see that the $\space y$-value of $\space Set_1\space$ within this subset contains all odd numbers greater than one, and therefore contains all primes except $\space2.\quad$ Not all radii are primes but there are infinite hypotenuse values, a sample shown
[here](https://oeis.org/A020882)
, and an infinite number of primes within these values. In the table below, you can see prime radius values outside of $\space Set_1\space$ but only $\space Set_1\space$ can contain concurrent prime $\space y$-values and $\space r$-values because $\space y\space$ is always composite if
$\space n>1.\quad$ A=y factors as
$$A=y=(2n-1)^2+2(2n-1)k=(2 n - 1) (2 k + 2 n - 1)$$

\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
n & k=1 & k=2 & k=3 & k=4 & k=5  \\ \hline
Set_1 & 3,4,5 & 5,12,13& 7,24,25& 9,40,41& 11,60,61  \\ \hline
Set_2 & 15,8,17 & 21,20,29 &27,36,45 &33,56,65 & 39,80,89  \\ \hline
Set_3 & 35,12,37 & 45,28,53 &55,48,73 &65,72,97 &  75,100,125 \\ \hline
Set_{4} &63,16,65 &77,36,85 &91,60,109 &105,88,137 &119,120,169 \\ \hline
Set_{5} &99,20,101 &117,44,125 &135,72,153 &153,104,185 &171,140,221 \\ \hline
\end{array}